# mailchimp sends response at Status:404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried mailchimp API to create a mailing list for newsletter but the response I'm getting is 404

I don't understand I checked everything again and again but still it showing 404
maybe the endpoint is incorrect but I got that from their documentation

endpoint: https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/

I already changed my server to us7 as API says

API: de5bbb37311bd90fe9264e991bc7c83f-us7
list id: 81937afd8f

[

```js
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var fname = req.body.firstname;
  var lname = req.body.lastname;
  var email = req.body.email;

  const data = {
    memebrs: [
      {
        email_address: email,
        status: "subscribed",
        merge_fields: {
          FNAME: fname,
          LNAME: lname,
      }

      }
    ]
  }

  const jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);

  const url = "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/81937afd8f";

  const options = {
    meathod: "POST",
    auth: "rootacess3000:de5bbb37311bd90fe9264e991bc7c83f-us7"
  }

  const request = https.request(url,options,function(response){
    response.on("data", function(data){
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    })
  })

  request.write(jsondata);
  request.end();

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("sever is running on port 3000");
});
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4RTL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so here's the correction:

1. your `url = "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/81937afd8f";` is wrong it should be `url = "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/81937afd8f";`
2. There's a typo in spelling of method, it's not "meathod" it's "method"